# Mean value not explicitly formulated in analytical form

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I can't understand why in the mean value Cauchy’s Theorem (  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) ), the mean value
cannot be explicitly figured out in an analytical form.

Can you give me a brief explanation of this fact?

Comment: What do you mean by analytical form?

Comment: Are you asking why a solution $c$ of the equation $(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a) =f'(c)$ cannot always be determined explicitly? Many equations do not have explicit solutions, and $c$ need not even be unique. Try it with $f(z) = \sin(z^2)$, $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Also often an explicit solution is not needed, only the *existance* of such a $c$ is important, e.g. to prove that $f'(x) \ge 0$ implies that $f$ is increasing.